# Jquery File uploader in Twig file not working

Tags: symfony

I am using this code for jquery file uploader i found(plugin) in this some lib files is given  which i have included but still getting error in my twig file.

Lib file is : tmpl.min.js

Error-: unclosed for and Unexpected character ";"  at line 1

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
    Line 1:     {% for (var i=0,file; file=o.files[i]; i++) {  %}

             <tr class="template-upload fade">
                <td>
                   <span class="preview"></span>
                </td>
               <td>
                <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
                {% if (file.error) { %}
                    <div>
                 <span class="label label-danger">Error</span>    {%=file.error%}   </div>
                {% } %}
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</p>
                {% if (!o.files.error) { %}
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;">   </div>
                         </div>
                    {% } %}
                </td>
                <td>
                     {% if (!o.files.error && !i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                         <button class="btn blue start btn-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                        <span>Start</span>
                        </button>
                    {% } %}
                    {% if (!i) { %}
                        <button class="btn red cancel btn-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
                        <span>Cancel</span>
                       </button>
                    {% } %}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% } %}
     </script>
```

Can any one help me please what is that exact error. i am unable to figure out.

Comment: why did you put your first line javascript inside `{% %}`? or maybe you want that be a twig loop?

Answer (score 3):

The error is because of conflicting  template syntax. Your javaScript template library using the same `{%  %}` code block.

You can tell twig not to parse your js template using [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html)

```
{% verbatim %}

       Put your js template script here        

{% endverbatim %}
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: Now browsed  files are not posted on server side using post method.can you please suggest what colud be the problem

Comment: @user3458514: On this context or with this much information, I can't suggest any solution for your new(!) problem. I'm sure you are not telling, file was posted on server side before you fixed your problem! You can ask another question for your problem, with appropriate code sample/error description. I'm sure someone with proper expertise will be able to help you.

Comment: As I can see from your profile you are new to stackoverflow. Please take a time to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).